# templateUrl not rendering when modal opened from iFrame

Tags: angularjs

I have a situation in the application, where I want to load an already available modal, in an iFrame of another application using the same codebase. For this I have used the following code :

**new-user-module.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('mo.pages.new-user.layouts', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'mo.pages.new-user.services'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', newUserRouteConfiguration]);

function newUserRouteConfiguration($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('new-user', {
            url: '/new-user',
            onEnter: [
                'mo.pages.new-user.services.NewUserPageService', function (newAttachmentPageService) {
                    newAttachmentPageService.openAttachmentModal();
                }
            ]
        });
}})();
```

**new-user-service.js**

```
(function () {

'use strict';

angular
    .module('mo.pages.new-user.services')
    .service('mo.pages.new-user.services.NewUserPageService', NewUserPageServiceFactory);

NewUserPageServiceFactory.$inject = [
    '$stateParams',
    '$modal'
];

function NewUserPageServiceFactory($stateParams, $modal) {
    var service = {
        openUserModal: openUserModal
    };

    return service;

    function openUserModal() {
        return function () {
            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'modules/pages/shared/modals/new-user/new-user-modal.html',
                controller: 'mo.pages.shared.modals.NewUserModalController as vm',
                windowClass: 'new-user-modal',
                resolve: {
                    headerText: function() {
                        return 'header';
                    }
                },
                backdrop: 'static',
                size: 'lg'
            });
        };
    }
}})();
```

The issue, I am facing is that, the modal is loading, when the '/new-user' is getting called in the iFrame, but the templateUrl is not loading.

Comment: Inspect the actual template request in dev tools network for clues

Comment: The template request is as expected, but its still not loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your console, I think you may find an error with your call to `newAttachmentPageService.openAttachmentModal();`

Since `NewUserPageServiceFactory` is registered as a *service* and not really a *factory*, it should not `return` anything. You should just be adding the method to the service object, for example:

```
function NewUserPageServiceFactory($stateParams, $modal) {
    this.openUserModal = function() {
        return function () {
            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'modules/pages/shared/modals/new-user/new-user-modal.html',
                controller: 'mo.pages.shared.modals.NewUserModalController as vm',
                windowClass: 'new-user-modal',
                resolve: {
                    headerText: function() {
                        return 'header';
                    }
                },
                backdrop: 'static',
                size: 'lg'
            });
        };
    }
}
```

For a good illustration of the (*slight*) differences between services and factories [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/manishchhabra/ne5p8/)

Let me know if this works